# How to Connect to Local SQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just started learning MySQL, when I was installing MySQL server and MySQL workbench I was configuring the server and accidentally I hit cancel, now when I try to create a connection to a local host it won't work.
how I can reconfigure it again?

Comment: is there any error message? can you post it? also `SQL server` would mislead people to think it's microsoft sql server instead of mysql

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check if Mysql is working go to console and type:

systemctl status mysql

It should be active, if not press:

systemctl start mysql

Then you need to go mysqlWorbench to Mysql connections, create one, leave hostname: 127.0.0.1 and the default port 3306 username root and just put the password, to put it you need to hit "Stored in Keychain", finally you need to press "Ok" and you will have a new connection created.